# Twitter Bootstrap glyphicons font's not found when using assetic in prod on Symfony2

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, assetic

I've read a lot of posts about this  but couldn't get this to work for my project.

So basiclly I have a Symfony2 project which includes twitter bootstrap (v3). Every thing works fine in dev mode but when I try it in prod mode i got errors saying that the twitter bootstrap fonts couldn't be found:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/Symfony/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff   
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/Symfony/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf  
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/Symfony/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular
```

Which is normal cause I dont have a css/ folder in Symfony/

Here is how the project is structured:

```
app/
src/
vendor/
web/
   css/
      compiled/
   fonts/
   js/
```

twig file:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets output="css/compiled/main.css" filter='cssrewrite'
        'css/bootstrap.min.css'
        'css/general.css'
        'css/navigation.css'
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

I used:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

I've checked in the bootstrap.min.css (in web/css/compiled) files (prod and dev) and they both have the same path for the fonts. Something like (../../../fonts/fontName.ext).

If we look at the path it shouldn't work neither in dev nor in prod mode as the path puts the fonts/ file outside the web directory. Yet, it works in dev mode.

Any idea on how to resolve this ?

I would be greatful.

Comment: Could you try to move `fonts` directory into `css` directory?

Comment: I'd already tried that and it didn't work

Comment: Did-you try to just remove "output" property  ? (in order to exclude some relative-path issue)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use the "cssrewrite" filter, it rewrites the path to the font-files (to their original source) as **Maxoo** already said.

You can add the assetic path for the font-files in the following way (so they are copied to the `css/fonts/` folder and the css-files will find them by using the orginal `../fonts/` path)

I've used the following solution:

**config.yml:**

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    assets:
        bootstrap_fonts_woff:
            inputs:
                - 'original/path/to/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff'
            output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
        bootstrap_fonts_ttf:            
            inputs:
                - 'original/path/to/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf'
            output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
        bootstrap_fonts_svg:
            inputs:
                - 'original/path/to/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg'
            output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
        bootstrap_fonts_eot:
            inputs:
                - 'original/path/to/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'
            output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
```

Then call

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

which should export the files to the fonts-directory inside your web-folder.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does help... It is in fact the only real solution so far and much better as any other (bad) solutions I've found everywhere else. I have to say that assetic is really bad for this and I hope this weird bug (yes this is a bug IMO) will be corrected one day. :/

Comment: Just add this:
if working in the dev env, it doesn't work if filter='cssrewrite' is here. I needed to remove it to have this nice solution working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to search them under `Symfony/` path, infact Symfony2 webfolder is `web/` so url is "relative" to `web/` folder.

BTW, you have to use the following command

```
php app/console assets:install
```

If you like to have symlinks you could also add `--symlink` parameter to your command

### So what's the difference between assets:install and assetics:dump ?

`assets:install` will symlink or copy the desired resources to "public web folder"

`assetic:dump` will only combine all js into one

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunalty it isn't working. As I was saying I have my final css file (main.css) in web/css/compiled, the fonts in web/fonts but the url in the css file for the fonts is smthg like (../../../fonts/file.ext)

Comment: @kimimsc: do you receive any error? (see my update, I've remove --env=prod)

Comment: I don't have any errors when I execute these commands, just the errors saying the font files couldn't be found when I go to the webpage

Comment: @kimimsc: did you run the command as now is in my answer? You should receive some message from CLI

Comment: Yes just the basic message saying what and where it installed assets

Comment: Installing assets using the hard copy option
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
Installing assets for Battle4Fame\ShopBundle into web/bundles/shop
Installing assets for Battle4Fame\AccountBundle into web/bundles/account
Installing assets for Battle4Fame\ForumBundle into web/bundles/forum
Installing assets for Battle4Fame\NewsBundle into web/bundles/news
Installing assets for Battle4Fame\CurlApiCallerBundle into web/bundles/curlapicaller
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodistribution

Comment: @kimimsc: and did you dumped assitics after?

Comment: @kimimsc: maybe those icons aren't contained into assets and, so, aren't copied or linked? I don't know, you should investigate; from here, without any details, is difficult

Answer (score 0):

Proper Solution:

- Install Nodejs, setup symfony2 config file, it will compile cssrewrite filter of your choice into CSS automatically. This will resolve these errors.
- my config.yml and config_dev.yml looks like this just an assetic section - Be very careful with the path syntax or else you will get this error "An error occurred while running: ... Error: Cannot find module 'less'" Any many people ran into these 3 errors messages google this string to find out "An error occurred while running: Error: Cannot find module 'less'"

assetic:

```
debug: '%kernel.debug%'
use_controller:
       enabled: '%kernel.debug%'
       profiler: true
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    ###is for linux path i am on windows for dev and linux for prod
    less:
        ###node: /usr/bin/nodejs
        ###node_paths: [/usr/lib/nodejs]
        node: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe"
        node_paths: ["C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules"]
        apply_to: "\.less$"
```

- do not forget installing "npm install -g less"
- In my specific case: when doing "php app/console assetic:dump" I get this same error. This is because my Windows dev web server is setup like this: the web root is "C:\xampp\htdocs\" and the project is like this "C:\xampp\htdocs\phantom\" and the assetic:dump puts glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf, glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff, and glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 in "C:\xampp\htdocs\phantom\web\fonts" HOWEVER, when page is loaded it looks in "http://localhost/" as you can see this is the issue with my development setup. So i copy folder fonts "C:\xampp\htdocs\phantom\web\fonts" to web root "C:\xampp\htdocs\" That solves the problem.
- This will not happen in production environment where your server web root is "C:\xampp\htdocs\phantom\web\". I tested on a production server without need to manually copy the fonts folder to webroot.
- In addition, when running  the same command in your project directory "php app/console assetic:dump" you will get error like "FileError: '../bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less' wasn't found. Tried - ../bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less,C:\xampp\htdocs\phantom\vendor\mopa\bootstrap-bundle\Mopa\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\Resources\public\bootstrap" By the same token bootstrap was installed by "php app/console assets:install" in "C:\xampp\htdocs\phantom\web\bootstrap" which is not correct webroot directory so again to resolve this same temporary issue in development i will just copy directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\phantom\web\bootstrap" to "C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap" that solves problem. Run your command again it will compile to css nicely and cleanly.

Comment: Looks like you forgot the example ;).

Answer (score -1):

May be you should try to keep the Bootstrap folder structure unchanged (downloading it with bower for example). By the way the cssrewrite filter will parse your css files to reflect the location of the fonts.