# How to add TwitterBootstrap to Symfony2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I want to use TwitterBootstrap in my Symfony2 bundle. Please give me a advise how to do that right way.
I use composer to install TwitterBootstrap into my vendor derectory (composer require twitter/bootstrap). 
How to link css & js in to my twig template?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the help.

For now I don`t  want to use additional bundles or other thinks. I just want to connect css and js files to my template.

Solution I use for now is:

1. Install fia composer jquery and twitterbootstrap in vendor/components/jquery and vendor/twbs/bootstrap directories
2. In `config.yml` I create a named assets:

   ```
   # Assetic Configuration
   assetic:
       assets:
           twbs_js_and_jq:
               inputs:
                   - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js'
                   - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
           twbs_css:
               inputs:
                    - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
           bootstrap_fonts_woff:
               inputs:
                   - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff'
               output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
       bootstrap_fonts_ttf:            
               inputs:
                   - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf'
               output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
       bootstrap_fonts_svg:
           inputs:
               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg'
           output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
       bootstrap_fonts_eot:
           inputs:
               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'
   ```

   It's important to create jQuery asset first. Assetic changes the paths to your assets, this will break any background images (or other paths) that uses relative paths, so I ned to add rule for the font files to make glyphicons work ([find example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864784/twitter-bootstrap-glyphicons-fonts-not-found-when-using-assetic-in-prod-on-symf)).
3. In the head section of `layout.html.twig` file I paste:

   ```
   {% javascripts '@twbs_js_and_jq' %}
       <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
   {% endjavascripts %}

   {% stylesheets '@twbs_css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
   {% endstylesheets %}
   ```

All worked!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to integrate Bootstrap is to declare the stylesheet in the `base.html.twig` file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

You can also use `asset` to load your stylesheet. Have a look to [Templating with Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html)

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to link styles from not public directory (from vendor/twitter/bootstrap)?

Comment: Yes, you just have to hard-code the stylesheet in your templates. And not use `asset`

Comment: I use assetic to link TB from vendor directory. Named assets with link : `'%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'`

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use the [MopaBootstrapBundle](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle).
With this Bundle you get a really great integration into Symfony, for example twig extensions and templates for use with Symfony Form component, so you don't need to style everything by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As all knows Bootstrap is related to assets, and all third party bundles, or direct includes lookls ugly (mostly form `/vendor/` directory do not do this!). So better use Bower what created special for managing your asstes. You can configura it for install all assets to Symfony2 `web` directory and then use `assets` in twig. Here is some links for documentation:

[Instalation guide](http://bower.io/#install-bower)

[Configuration](http://bower.io/docs/config/)

Hope this will help to you :)